# How to get data from website with py-requets?

Tags: python, video, download, python-requests

I am trying to download a video from `youtube.com` and save it into a file.
Thought I can do this with pythons `requests`.

Here is my little code:

```
import sys
import requests

def download_file ( url ):
    local_filename = url.split( '/' )[-1]
    r = requests.get( url, stream = True )

    with open( local_filename, 'wb' ) as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content( chunk_size=1024 ): 
                f.write( chunk )

def main ( ):
    url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q6UJcLyYJ14'
    download_file( url )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main( )
```

My hope was that the data would be streamed into the file. But this isn't the case. I'm just gettin the html code into the file and then the program ends.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help with that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that youtube videos aren't static files on the web url that you have. If you inspect the html code you'll see that the src of the video is not the page that you have. Even if you were to replace the url with the 'src', I don't think youtube will allow you to download the videos the way you want to.

```
<video tabindex="-1" class="video-stream html5-main-video"
       style="width: 640px; height: 360px; left: 0px; 
       top: 0px; opacity: 1;" src="blob:https://www.youtube.com/e779f2eb-
       b153-4022-a888-1b9b34b9dfa8">
</video>
```

Comment: Thank you. But there must be a way. Since there are a lot of youtube & co downloaders out there.

Comment: Yes, but many of those work completely differently than trying to download the video directly.  Read this post: http://superuser.com/questions/773719/how-do-all-of-these-save-video-from-youtube-services-work